# Unable to get Facebook Friends in PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get facebook friends using php SDK. I cannot use Latest PHP SDK as it is using namespaces and my application doesn't support namespaces. I get following permissions from user

```
email,user_birthday,user_status,publish_stream,offline_access,user_friends
```

And when the code is executed, it shows the following `Facebook OATH Dialogue`

[image]

And you can see in the image that it doens't show user friends permission.

And when I want to get user's friends using PHP SDK using following code:

```
    require_once(APPLICATION_PATH_LIB . "/Facebook/facebook.php");
    $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $appId, 'secret' => $appSecret));
    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
            "client_id=" . $appId .
            "&client_secret=" . $appSecret .
            "&grant_type=client_credentials";
    $app_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $app_token = explode("=", $app_token);

    $app_token = $app_token[1];

    $user = $facebook->getUser();



    if ($user) {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', array('access_token' => $app_token));
        //echo '<pre>';var_dump($user_profile);die;
        $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends', array('access_token' => $app_token));

       echo '<pre>';print_r($friends);
    }
```

And it is giving me following error

```
OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Comment: Start by removing publish_stream, offline_access. They don't exists anymore. And it say friend list in the screenshot. And the error say that you have to use a user access token. Sounds like you are using an app access token

Comment: So What access token I should use?

Comment: @WizKid How do I GET that?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: Read that but couldn't be able to understand

Answer (score 1):

They actually disabled this relatively recently---

You can now only get a list of facebook friends who are also using your app.

See this [GraphAPI reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends/)

(Second point under "Permissions")

There seems to be some disagreement about this, but, according to @drmarvelous, you *can* get the users' full list of friends if you submit your application for review and request that permission through the "Status & Review" section under your app. 
But, this process can take some time, and you may not even be granted the permission --

Comment: To add to this:
In order to get raw access to the friends list you must request access from Facebook (who will review your application thoroughly)

Comment: So I cannot get all friends of user?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You can only get a list of friends that are using your application now (without requesting special permissions for your app from Facebook themselves)

Comment: Oh, Well then I was mistaken - 
I will edit my answer, accordingly -

Comment: even WITH permission from facebook, it is not possible to get the full list with the /me/friends endpoint anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the full list of your friends, you'll need the [invitable_friends API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/). Note that this only works for facebook games.

Comment: That should not be abused for any other purpose though.